# How do I interpret tf.keras.Model.predict() output?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I am having trouble finding the documentation I need on this. To summarize the issue, I have trained a tf.keras model using two classes of images, labeled as '0' or '1'. I now want to use this model to predict whether new images are a '0' or '1'. My question is as follows: `model.predict()` returns a number between 1 and 0, but I can't seem to find what exactly this is. Is it correct to say that this is it's prediction (ie, closer to 1 means the image is likely a 1, and closer to 0 means the image is likely a 0)? Or is there something else going on here. I have included the code, and some output, below. In this case, is `pred` the probability the image is a 1, and `1 - pred` the probability the image is a 0?

Thanks for any and all help.

```
for img_path in test_filenames:
   img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE))
   img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
   img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
   pred = model.predict(img_array)
   print(pred)
```

Returns

```
[[0.8361757]]
[[0.26765466]]
[[0.2722953]]
[[0.81938094]]
[[0.24995388]]
[[0.45974937]]
```

Comment: Note that interpreting the output of model.predict requires knowing what the model outputs, since predict just makes a forward pass of your model. So please include some information about your model, specially the output and loss.

Answer (score 1):

> is `pred` the probability the image is a 1, and `1 - pred` the probability the image is a 0?

Yes, that is correct. If you want to get hard class (i.e., 0 or 1), then you can threshold the output. 0.5 is a common threshold, but I have also seen 0.3. This is something you can tune.

```
pred = model.predict(img_array)
classes = pred > 0.5
```

The predictions are between 0 and 1 most likely because the last activation of the model is a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up. Last check - this still applies if the final layer activation is sigmoid correct? eg `outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)`

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant sigmoid :) You would use softwax for multiple classes.